# Numerically finding periodic solution to Riccati equation with a scalar unknown parameter

Tags: differential-equations, oc.optimization-and-control

We have a Riccati equation with an unknown scalar parameter $a$. It is proven to have unique real solution pair $\{y(x), a\}$ exists so that $y$ is periodic:
$$
y'=ap_{0}(x)+q_{0}(x)+q_{1}(x)y+q_{2}(x)y^{2}
$$
where $p_0, q_0, q_1, q_2$ are periodic. We don't know their functional form, but know their values sampled on uniformly spaced grids from 0 to $2\pi$.

Are there good ways to numerically find the periodic solution $y$ and the corresponding free parameter $a$? I cannot think of better ways than treating this as an IVP, then optimize the initial condition and $a$ using the periodic BC as objective.